# Is a temporary value created in this code?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
class B;

class A
{
  public:
    A() {}
    A(B &b);
};

class B {};

A::A(B &b) {}

int main()
{
    B b;

    const A &refa = b;// does this line create a temporary value?

    return 0;
}
```

My question is: does the code `const A &refa = b;` create a temporary value or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a temporary object `A(b)` is created in the intialization statement, and it is immediately bound to the constant-reference `refa`. This has the effect of prolonging the lifetime of the temporary to match the scope of the `refa` variable.

Comment: and Under what circumstances ,"const TYPE &" would create  a temporary object?

Comment: consider: int i;int const& refi=i; would not create a temporary object,and what is the matter?

Comment: @hu wang you can confirm this easily by putting some printf into A::A(B& b)

Comment: 不同类型(A和B)的变量间是不会实现名绑定的。编译器会先调用被绑定类型（也就是const A & refa中的A类型）变量的构造函数，传入b，构造一个A(b)的临时对象，然后把这个临时对象绑定到refa。

Comment: @Y.Z:为什么不同类型(A和B)的变量间是不会实现名绑定的,有这样的规则嘛?

Comment: 除了可以隐式转换的类型以外，名绑定是要经过类型检查的。否则就不是强类型了。试想如果可以`int i; const char & x=i;`，那岂不是变量名x,i可以随意表示任意类型的对象了么？Name binding between variables of different types is not applicable. In the codes you provide in above comment, refi and i are names of the same type, so no temporary object is created in the process of binding. Keep in mind that the hint is not about reference, name or binding but type here to understand.